# Variable with default access keyword is unable to be accessed in same package's different class

Tags: java, default

When I access a default (with no access modifier like public or private in front of it) access variable like `String s = "hello"` from a `class A` in package `com.access.test` to `class B` in same package, I can't obtain the variable `s` in `class B`. 
IDE shows that variable `s` is never defined.

But then why does Java say that default access variables can be accessed in the same package. Just like we know that a protected variable can be accessed from different package by extending the class.
So a default variable should be accesses without even making its `class A`'s object instantiation(`A a =  new A()` and then `a.s`).
Please explain.

Comment: Do both class files locate at the same folder?

Comment: No , I don't think so. They are under same package in eclipse.

Comment: If they locate in different folders, they are treated as been in different packages. There are no package hierarchy in Java, i. e. class in package `a.b.c` won't see package-private fields and methods from classes of package `a.b` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it in B via instance of A.

So do it like:

```
A a = new A();
//print a.s
```

If you define String `a` as static then you could access it by class name in B like:

```
//print A.s
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing Class A's Variable directly outside the class even though within the same package is not possible.

Think about it in a simple way, Class B is in the same package but not inheriting class A, right!

So  `String s;` is not a part of `class B`. Then how can it be accessed directly. You have to create an object of `class A` in `class B` and then `String s` will be accessible.

Just go for the basics of Access Modifiers in Java and you'll come to know that even public variables of a class cannot be accessed outside the class, without its object.

for example:

```
class Test5
{
    public int x=10;
}
class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        //System.out.println(x); //Generates Compile Time Error
        Test5 obj= new Test5();
        System.out.println(obj.x);
    }
}
```

In this example, `x` is public but still not accessible without object of class `Test5` even though both the classes are in the same program file.

Same is the case with default modifier also.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two classes

```
public ClassA {
    String myA = "A string";
}
```

and

```
public ClassB {
    String myB = "B string";
}
```

I think you may be confusing **accessibility** and **namespace**.  Each class definition creates its own namespace.  This enables you to create identically named instance fields in separate classes that are still separately encapsulated within each class.

If you wish to access an instance field that has default access in the same package but in a separate class, you must qualify that field name with a class instance (so that the compiler will know where to locate the field; if you do not quality the field name then it is assumed you are only wishing to consider field names in the current scope).  For example, to access `myA` from `ClassB` you would write:

```
a = new ClassA();
System.out.println("myA = " + a.myA);
```